# ffmpeg result to a tempfile

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am new to python and ffmpeg. I have a following question to ask.

If I run the following command from command-line and it works.

```
ffmpeg -i  1.flv  temp_filename
```

If I put it in a program

```
   temp_file_handle, temp_filename = tempfile.mkstemp('.flv')

   command = "ffmpeg -i " + newvideo.location + " "+ temp_filename

   out = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
   res = out.communicate()
```

The generated video didn't write to the tem_filename. Why?

Comment: Did you print out what the temp_filename is and check if it really exists or not?

Comment: Yes, the file exists. The output is: temp file name:  /tmp/tmpyuLbPc.flv, but the size of this file is 0 byte

Comment: Do you have a space between the two file names?

Comment: Try `temp_file_handle.flush()` at the end of your code, maybe.

Comment: Yes, there is a space. If I replace temp_filename with a file under the /home directory. Everything works. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mkstemp`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) creates the file itself, not just the file name.  So the file will already exist when `ffmpeg` attempts to write to it.  Therefore it will ask whether you want to overwrite the file, or produce an error message, unless the `ffmpeg -y` option is used.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be better off creating a temporary *directory*, so that `ffmpeg` can *create* the output file for you. It is probably failing to operate because `mkstemp` creates the file, not just the filename.

Use the following context manager, it'll clean up after you when done:

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tempfilename(extension):
    dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    yield os.path.join(dir, 'tempoutput' + extension)
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
```

Also, it would be far easier for you to pass in the arguments *without* the `shell=True` switch and the command as a list. Here is the above context manager in action with the command split into a list:

```
with tempfilename('.flv') as temp_filename:
    command = ["ffmpeg", "-i", newvideo.location, temp_filename]
    out = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This way the shell cannot mis-interpret special characters in the `location` and `temp_filename` arguments. The context manager provides the filename without creating it, but will still clean up after itself.